# jQuery Filter with Images

Tags: jquery, filter

I am looking for a jQuery Script to Multi Filter Images. The Images should be hidden and show only if any Filter is clicked. I have seen a nice Demo on a Page which i wish to do the same but with hidden Images at first.
http://themetrust.com/demos/reveal/

Here is how i think: http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/6856/filtert.jpg

Answer (score 0):

[QuickSand](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/), or something very similar should be what you're looking for. You may need to do a little tweaking to get the images hidden initially - I'm not super-familiar with the plugin. Once thought is to have a category which no images fall under (you could name it `blank`) and when you click it (or in our case, have the page default to it) no images would be visible.

Answer (score 0):

It should be fairly easy to build your own. Maybe this will give you some ideas: http://jsfiddle.net/ZLfQG/2/

#### HTML

```
<div id="filter">
    <a href="#">Show All</a> |
    <a href="#" rel="cat">Show Cats</a> |
    <a href="#" rel="dog">Show Dogs</a> |
    <a href="#" rel="bird">Show Birds</a> |
    <a href="#" rel="none">Show None</a>
</div>

<hr />

<img src="cat1.jpg" class="cat" />
<img src="dog1.jpg" class="dog" />
<img src="dog2.jpg" class="dog" />
<img src="bird1.jpg" class="bird" />
<img src="cat2.jpg" class="cat" />
<img src="bird2.jpg" class="bird" />
<img src="cat3.jpg" class="cat" />
<img src="dog3.jpg" class="dog" />
<img src="bird3.jpg" class="bird" />
```

#### CSS

```
img {
    display: none;
}
```

#### JS

```
$('#filter a').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('rel')) {
        $('img').hide().filter('[class="' + $(this).attr('rel') + '"]').show();
    } else {
        $('img').show();
    }
    
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.. I solved my way like below.. How can i add effects like slide or fade? http://jsfiddle.net/UJJCH/1/

Comment: Check this out: [slide](http://jsfiddle.net/UJJCH/3/) and [fade](http://jsfiddle.net/UJJCH/2/)